# Issues with popup window in IE8

Tags: internet-explorer-8, kendo-ui

We have a catalog browser for products were the user can click and it opens a window to show the product details, this works fine in Chrome, but when tried on IE8 the popup window close button is not showing, i still can click on it, but it is not visible.

Here is my code:

`<div class="k-window-titlebar k-header" style="margin-top: -32px;">&nbsp;<span class="k-window-title" id="productView_wnd_title" style="right: 30px;"></span><div class="k-window-actions"><a role="button" href="#" class="k-window-action k-link"><span role="presentation" class="k-icon k-i-close">Close</span></a></div></div>`

We are using .net asp mvc and kendoui.

Any ideas on what to do for fixing it?

Thanks!

Edit: found a reference to similar issue on kendo forums: [window-widget-problems-on-ie8](http://www.kendoui.com/forums/kendo-ui-web/window/window-widget-problems-on-ie8.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Already found the issue, the bundle for css had missing the kendo version on path.